# appcompat 25.1.1 is showing error in android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-studio-2.3

after updating android studio 2.2 to 2.3 appcompat 25.1.1 is showing error **com.android.support libraries must use the same version**. in studio 2.2 it was working fine, in 2.3 it is only showing error but app is running fine, i have attached below one screen shot of the error.

[image: appcompat is showing error in android studio 2.3]

Comment: show your full gradle file

Comment: post your gradle file buddy.

Comment: All your com.android.support library should be of same version

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your build.gradle (app) just before dependencies

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project `Files/My project/.idea/libraries` and see what your librarie are different. Include this different librarie with same version in gradle file. Sync your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different version of support library. Use same version for all type of support artifacts.

Answer (score -1):

Change it according to buildtool version. like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
}

}

dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
}
```

Comment: what if he wants to use latest version?

Comment: and.. "your appcompat version and buildTools version should be same". this is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Please add below line

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0'
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Nope - `Error:(66, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0`

Comment: are you using the 2.3 studio series?
Then only this will work.